Flutter web TextFiled in HTML iframe on chrome not working properly
I have this odd case, and I can’t find a solution anywhere.
I have built a Flutter web app that I have embedded in an HTML page using the iframe tag. Only on Chromium-based browsers, the TextField is not getting focus when the user clicks on it. Instead, they must hover over the border to activate input.
Any ideas?
I have tried changing the renders and CanvasKitVariant, but nothing seems to work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
